# Nginx を再起動しても、php-fpm を再起動したことにはなりませんか？

Tags: php, nginx

Nginx と php-fpm の関係性を理解できていません。
何となく、Nginx の上に php-fpm が載っているようなイメージを抱いているのですが、
例えば、Nginx を再起動しても、php-fpm を再起動したことにはならないのですか？

質問背景
原因は不明ですが、朝確認してみたら「作成しているWebサイトの表示だけ」がとても遅くなっていることがあります。
何か遅いプロセスか何かが走っているのかと思い、取り敢えず、Nginx と MySQL を再起動しています。
これまでは php-fpm を再起動 していなかったのですが、ふと Nginx を再起動しても、php-fpm を再起動 したことにはならないのかと思い、質問しました。
環境は、CentOS7です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問の冒頭：

> Nginx と php-fpm の関係性を理解できていません。
> 何となく、Nginx の上に php-fpm が載っているようなイメージを抱いているのですが、
> 例えば、Nginx を再起動しても、php-fpm を再起動したことにはならないのですか？

それについては、この記事の図が分かりやすいのでは？
[NginxでPHPを動かす](https://www.spiceworks.co.jp/blog/?p=12317)

> ・PHP-FPMというのは、PHP-FastCGI Process Managerの略で、cgiです。
> ・PHP-FPM(=FastCGIのインターフェース) → このプログラムを使って、PHPを動作をさせます
> ▼ cgi方式
> nginxがphp-fpmにphpの処理を依頼し、php-fpmがphpを処理します。
> (紹介先記事にこんな感じの図があるので参照してください。)
>
> ```
> +---------+    +---------+    +---------+
> |  NGINX  | -> | PHP-FPM | -> |   PHP   |
> +---------+    +---------+    +---------+
> ```
>
> ▼設定方法
> ・ここでは、nginx→php-fpmの通信はUnixドメインソケット通信です

> 最後にnginxとphp-fpmを再起動
>
> ```
> service nginx restart
> service php-fpm restart
> ```
>
> これでPHPが動くようになります

補足はこの記事で。
[FastCGI - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI)

> 詳細
> リクエスト毎に新しいプロセスを作成する代わりに、FastCGI は永続的なプロセスを使用して一連のリクエストを処理する。これらのプロセスは、WebサーバではなくFastCGI サーバが所有している。
>
> Webサイトの管理者とプログラマは、FastCGI でWebサーバからWebアプリケーションを分離すると、組み込みインタプリタ(mod_perl（英語版）やmod_php（英語版）等)に比べて多くの利点がある。この分離により、サーバプロセスとアプリケーションプロセスを個別に再起動できる。

回答として：
つまり **「個別に再起動できる。」** ということは、裏返せば **「個別に再起動しなければならない。」** ことでもあるでしょう。

なので、**「Nginx を再起動しても、php-fpm を再起動したことにはならない」** と考えられます。

他にはこんな記事も
[How to Connect NGINX to PHP-FPM Using UNIX or TCP/IP Socket](https://www.tecmint.com/connect-nginx-to-php-fpm/)

> Next, you need to restart the two services to apply the changes, using the systemctl command.
>
> ```
> ------------- On CentOS/RHEL and Fedora  -------------
> # systemctl restart nginx
> # systemctl restart php-fpm
> ```